# CalendarBundle installation on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, calendar, installation

I have tried to install CalendarBundle by reading this tutorial on this link: https://github.com/carlescliment/calendar-bundle but the problem is whenever I try to create a new bundle (step 4 at the tutorial: "Create your calendar bundle") this error message is displayed:

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]

The child node "driver" at path "blade_tester_calendar" must be configured.

So, how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the configuration is missing. This is the [6th step](https://github.com/carlescliment/calendar-bundle#6-modify-your-appconfigconfigyml). So you'll have to follow all the steps from the tutorial before trying to use the bundle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, I could create a new bundle...but there is an other problem, in fact the view of the calendar doesn't work, there are some things missing into CSS files, well I think it is better that I look for an other solution, and by the way, I tried to install CalendarBundle - jQuery fullcalendar bundle, but I met some problems when I tried to install FOSJsRouting bundle, please have a look at this link to learn more about the issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666989/fosjsroutingbundle-installation-on-symfony2?noredirect=1#comment34529163_22666989 

Thanks in advance