# FOSJsRoutingBundle installation on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, installation, bundle

I have tried to install FOSJsRoutingBundle through reading this tutorial on this link: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md
but whenever I run this command

```
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

the following list of errors messages is displayed:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle' not
>   found in C:\wamp\www\calendar\app\AppKernel.php on line 19
>
> PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\calendar\app\console:0
>   PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
>   C:\wamp\www\calendar\app\console:27
>   PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun()
>   C:\wamp\www\calendar\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:121
>   PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
>   C:\wamp\www\calendar\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:70
>   PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
>   C:\wamp\www\calendar\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2269
>   PHP   6. AppKernel->registerBundles() C:\wamp\www\calendar\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2439

I don't know why it indicates that the class 'FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle' not found is not found despite that class is declared at the file app/AppKernel.php as you can notice below:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

So, how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you run `composer.phar update` ?

Comment: yes I did, but when I run this command: $ php app/console assets:install --symlink web  again, I see this error message:

[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                                                                               
  Unable to create symlink due to error code 1314: 'A required privilege is not held by the client'. Do you have the required Administrator-rights?

Comment: Do you have the rights to create symlinks?

Comment: in fact I don't know...how can I know that???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the error in your comment above, you don't have the right. Can you try without the `--symlink` option? Is the problem in your question fixed?

Comment: well I tried an other method and it worked, in fact I tried to run the command-line interpreter as an administrator then to run the following command: php app/console assets:install --symlink web ... finally my problem is resolved, thanks a lot for your support my friend...merci bien mon ami :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
```

to your `app/AppKernel.php` file.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you've taken out the `new AppBundle\AppBundle(),` line out.... put it at the end of all the bundles in your AppKernel like below:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        );
    );
);
```